# How do I give a good estimate for $3^{3.8}$ or $3^{308}$ or $3^{3.7}$ etc. quickly and without a calculator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

How do I give a good estimate for $3^{3.8}$ or $3^{3.08}$ or $3^{3.7}$ etc. quickly and without a calculator?

Comment: If this is from a real job interview, then the point of the question isn't that you get the right answer. The point is that you _start working_ on things that _might seem reasonable_, regardless of whether you actually get to a correct answer in the end. It's not about whether you know how to approximate fractional exponents, but about how you attack a problem. So, in that spirit, you've shown us $\frac{81}{3^{0.2}}$. What can you tell me about $3^{0.2}$?

Comment: Well Now I am genuinly interested to know how to do it, I don't know how to estimate 3^0.2, but I can convert the problem roughly to e^x where x is a decimal

Answer (score 2):

Back of the envelope estimate of $3^{3.8}$ to follow:

We know $\log 3$ is slightly bigger than $1$.

Let $f(x) = 3^x$, so that $f'(x) = 3^x \log 3$.

If $x = 4$ and $dx = -.2$ then $y = 81$ and $dy = 3^4 \log 3 (-.2) = -16.2 (\log 3)$.

So a not-too-accurate guess using differentials could be $81 - 16.2(\log 3)$. Since $\log 3$ is slightly bigger than $1$ let's just call it $81 - 17 = 64$.

If you go a bit further and use the fact that $y = 3^x$ is convex, we know the initial estimate is going to be too low, so perhaps bump it up a bit to 65.

Comment: Ok cool, so is this the same as a taylor series round the closest, so $f\left( x_{0}+h\right) \approx f\left( x_{0}\right) -f'\left( x_{0}\right)  h$, where $x_{0}=4,h=-0.2$ in the example. Do you know if there is a good approximation method for e, as I can convert it to $e^x$

Answer (score 0):

The binomial theorem shows that $(1+0.2)^5<3<(1+0.3)^5$, and the difference is about equally large on either side of the inequality. So let's say $\sqrt[5]3\approx1.25$. Then
$$
\frac{81}{3^{0.2}}\approx 81\cdot\frac 45=64.8
$$

Comment: Ok, this is more accurate than the taylor expansion, where did you pluck $(1+0.2)^5<3<(1+0.3)^5$ from? I would only be able to show that by expanding them, and can you find other values this way?

Comment: @Tintatin I found them by trial and error (although not much was needed). $1.1^5<2$ is easy to see, and $1.5^5>6$ follows from $1.5^2>2$. From there, I just tried the remaining three one-decimal possibilities.

Comment: So have I got this clear, by inspection you can see $1.1^5<2$ and $1.5^5<6$, then you calculated $1.3^5, 1.4^5 , 1.5^5$ manually? , I feel like I have misinterpreted as isn't this trying values and interpolating, not the binomial theorem?

Comment: @Tinatim I use the binomial theorem to calculate $1.2^5$ and $1.3^5$, approximately (getting e.g. $1.2^5\approx1+5\cdot0.2+10\cdot0.04$ and stopping there). It's faster than actually multiplying out the $^5$, and I don't need more precision anyway.

Comment: Ah of course, that is pretty nifty, but quite hard to apply to other examples, and it is kind of guessing right, just that using the binomial theorem is a quick way to estimate $1.3^5$. Thanks as I forgot about that.  Say if I wanted to work out $\sqrt [3] {3}$ I could try creating bounds say $1.7^3$ and $1.1^3$, and then get it down to two decimals its between and approximate half way in between.

Comment: "but quite hard to apply to other examples" Many quick hand approximations are. It's a matter of having a repertoire of many different techniques and a gut sense of which ones work when. I am not very familiar with root approximation algorithms, so I adapt what I do know.

Comment: Ok understood, and thank you, I realise I am not supposed to write comments like this, it says move to the chat, but I do not have enough points

Comment: @Tinatim It's the same system on the entire Stackexchange network, and here on math.SE we have an unusually lax attitude to discussions in comments. I am also generally against using chat for this because by using comments there's a lot less pressure on being present and answering immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach is "purely rational", i.e., does not require the floating point computation of logarithms, etc.

Assume that we want to compute $3^x$ for arbitrary real $x>0$. Note that
$$3^x=\left({1\over 3}\right)^{-x}=\left(1-{2\over3}\right)^{-x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{-x\choose k}\left(-{2\over3}\right)^k=1+{2x\over3}+{2x(x+1)\over 9}+\ldots\quad.$$
The series is convergent for all $x>0$ (even for all $x\in{\mathbb C}$). When $x>0$ its terms start to decrease when $k>2x-3$.

Comment: Ok nice, Is this $$\left(1-{2\over3}\right)^{-x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{-x\choose k}\left(-{2\over3}\right)^k$$ just the binomial formula. I haven't seen that before, It's a shame it takes 30 terms to get close

Answer (score -1):

Do you know how these things are calculated in a calculator, they use the taylor approximation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

So if you could memorize up the first few terms of the series of $a^x$

$a^x = 1 + x log(a) +\frac{1}{2} x^2 log^2(a) + \frac{1}{6}x^3 log^3(a)....$

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+a%5Ex%5C

and if you know the $log_{10}$ values, this can be used.